# How to use LINQ with ServiceModel.Channels.Message

Tags: .net, linq, wcf

How can i use LINQ with ServiceModel.Channels.Message? I'd like to use LINQ to the SOAP message body.

I initially tried doing this:

```
XElement elem = XElement.load(message.GetReaderAtBodyContents());
```

But that piece of code complains that XMLReader should be EOF after the read operation. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I found a solution:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(message.GetReaderAtBodyContents().ReadOuterXml());
```